# what about dual in `\pointpoints{SingularText}{PluralText}`

Tags: languages, exam

when you need to change the language from English to another language has dual names, what should you do?

as In document class exam, when you need to change the points name, there is just singular"p=1" and plural"p=3-infinite"

```
\pointpoints{SingularText}{PluralText} %\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
```

so what about DualText"just when points =2"